# Field from parsed JSON undefined when console.log returning true value

Tags: json, typescript, react-native

Async Storage returns an item from storage as a string. Next, the string is parsed to an object. When trying to get data from the object, an undefined error is returned.

```js
const storage: any = await AsyncStorage.getItem('persist:root');

const state = JSON.parse(storage!);
console.log(state);

const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.auth));
console.log(a); <- Normal JSON with fields "user" and "token'
console.log(a.user); <- undefined
console.log(a.token); <- undefined

const refreshToken = a.token.refreshToken; <- undefined
```

Variable `state.auth` JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "user":{
},
  "token":{
    "refreshToken":"REFRESH",
    "accessToken":"ACCESS"
  }
}
```

> LOG  {"_persist": "{"version":-1,"rehydrated":true}", "auth":
> "{"user":{"user_id":19,"email":"user19@mail.ru","approved":false,"createdAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.762Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.762Z","role":{"role_id":1,"role_name":"Пользователь","createdAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:21.257Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:21.257Z"},"organization":{"organization_id":3,"organization_type_id":1,"organization_name":"ООО
> \"Компания 4\"","full_name":"ООО \"Компания
> 4\"","short_name":"Компания
> 4","register_number":"212122134","bic":"251490211","phone":"+79354944154","address":"883072,
> Курганская область, город Чехов, спуск Будапештсткая,
> 77","email":"company4@mail.com","ogrn":"6927890723831","inn":"0436981520","kpp":"183212273","okpo":"50235599","createdAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:23.354Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:23.354Z"},"person":{"person_id":19,"last_name":"Ivanov","first_name":"Ivan","patronymic":"Ivanovi3","gender":"Мужской","phone":"+79001234568","createdAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.760Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.760Z"},"group":null},"token":{"refreshToken":"REFRESH","accessToken":"ACCESS"}}"}
> LOG
> {"user":{"user_id":19,"email":"user19@mail.ru","approved":false,"createdAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.762Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.762Z","role":{"role_id":1,"role_name":"Пользователь","createdAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:21.257Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:21.257Z"},"organization":{"organization_id":3,"organization_type_id":1,"organization_name":"ООО
> "Компания 4"","full_name":"ООО "Компания
> 4"","short_name":"Компания
> 4","register_number":"212122134","bic":"251490211","phone":"+79354944154","address":"883072,
> Курганская область, город Чехов, спуск Будапештсткая,
> 77","email":"company4@mail.com","ogrn":"6927890723831","inn":"0436981520","kpp":"183212273","okpo":"50235599","createdAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:23.354Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-10T12:42:23.354Z"},"person":{"person_id":19,"last_name":"Ivanov","first_name":"Ivan","patronymic":"Ivanovi3","gender":"Мужской","phone":"+79001234568","createdAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.760Z","updatedAt":"2024-01-11T07:42:33.760Z"},"group":null},"token":{"refreshToken":"REFRESH","accessToken":"ACCESS"}}
> LOG  undefined LOG  undefined

Comment: please also show us all the values of the console logs you have called

Comment: You may also want to try a `console.log(state.auth.user);`.

Comment: `state.auth` is a string with a JSON *inside*. See how suddenly the backslashes appear, while they're not there for `"auth"` itself: `"auth": "{\"user\"`, the `"` before the opening curly brace is the start of the actual string.

Comment: @tevemadar The second log shows the normal parsed JSON of `state.auth`.

Comment: state.auth is already string so don't need to call stringy.

Comment: could you try to do console.log(Object.keys(a))?

Comment: @JonasBeck console.log(Object.keys(a)) returns an array of numbers from 0 to 1965.

Comment: @ION it means a is not a json object just string.

Comment: @JonasBeck removed stringify and its works. `const a = JSON.parse(state.auth);` Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`state` is the parsed `storage` JSON string. It's an object with `"_persist"`, `"auth"` and `"token"` keys. From here `state.auth` and `state.token` hold stringified JSON data, so these need to be parsed. ***Don't stringify and parse these values***. Doing so will result in the same original single-stringified value. Just parse them.

```js
const storage: any = await AsyncStorage.getItem('persist:root');

const state = JSON.parse(storage!);
console.log(state);

const a = JSON.parse(state.auth);
console.log(a); <- Normal JSON with fields "user" and "token'
console.log(a.user); <-- defined
console.log(a.token); <-- defined

const refreshToken = a.token.refreshToken; <-- "REFRESH"
```

```js
{
    "user": {
        "user_id": 19,
        "email": "user19@mail.ru",
        "approved": false,
        "createdAt": "2024-01-11T07:42:33.762Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-01-11T07:42:33.762Z",
        "role": {
            "role_id": 1,
            "role_name": "Пользователь",
            "createdAt": "2024-01-10T12:42:21.257Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-01-10T12:42:21.257Z"
        },
        "organization": {
            "organization_id": 3,
            "organization_type_id": 1,
            "organization_name": "ООО \"Компания 4\"",
            "full_name": "ООО \"Компания 4\"",
            "short_name": "Компания 4",
            "register_number": "212122134",
            "bic": "251490211",
            "phone": "+79354944154",
            "address": "883072, Курганская область, город Чехов, спуск Будапештсткая, 77",
            "email": "company4@mail.com",
            "ogrn": "6927890723831",
            "inn": "0436981520",
            "kpp": "183212273",
            "okpo": "50235599",
            "createdAt": "2024-01-10T12:42:23.354Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-01-10T12:42:23.354Z"
        },
        "person": {
            "person_id": 19,
            "last_name": "Ivanov",
            "first_name": "Ivan",
            "patronymic": "Ivanovi3",
            "gender": "Мужской",
            "phone": "+79001234568",
            "createdAt": "2024-01-11T07:42:33.760Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-01-11T07:42:33.760Z"
        },
        "group": null
    },
    "token": {
        "refreshToken": "REFRESH",
        "accessToken": "ACCESS"
    }
}
```